# How do I get voice over focus to my modal?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, accessibility

I am using iphone 6+ and with the voice over (accessibility) option on. I have my exit modal open on a link click and I set my keyboard focus on the modal (with js). This all works fine. However, the voice over focus is not switched to my modal, it is still on the trigger link.

How do I get the voice over focus to the modal?
Here is the modal code

```
<div class="modal-container" id="{{ modalModel.modalId }}">
    <div class="modal-mask" data-ng-click="onMaskClick($event)">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-label="{{ modalModel.modalTitle }}">
        <div class="modal-body-container">
            <h4 class="modal-title heading-4">{{ modalModel.modalTitle }}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="modal-close" data-ng-click="closeModal($event)">
                <span class="btn-text">close</span>
                <span class="icon chrome-blue-x-round"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-contents">
                <div class="modal-contents-wrapper" data-ng-transclude></div>
                xxxxxx xxxx
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `modal-body` class element has focus when the modal pops up. I am using iOS 9.

Comment: @dandavis it is there to prevent users from tabbing to it when it is not visible. I can focus on it fine but the voice over focus/cursor would not go on it

Comment: do you have an example we can try.  i've done this before and it works ok.  it'd help to see your code in action.

Comment: The entire code is just too much and too complicated to paste here or even to set up a fiddle. The modal pops and the focus is on the modal body right now but the voice over cursor does not move to the modal. I have a suspicion that it is because I am not focusing on a normal keyboard accessible item. I am going to try to make it focus on the close `button` and will post answer if it works

Comment: since your sample code had tabindex='-1', that should be sufficient to make your object a "normal keyboard accessible item".

Comment: @slugolicious the keyboard focus is fine for the modal, the issue was the voice over cursor/focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I was able to focus the voice over cursor in the modal by putting the keyboard focus on the close button when the modal opens.**

It appears if the keyboard focus is not on an element which the keyboard can focus on naturally, then the voice over cursor will not move inside of the modal. Since the close button is a button, this worked

```
        <button type="button" class="modal-close" data-ng-click="closeModal($event)">
            <span class="btn-text">close</span>
            <span class="icon chrome-blue-x-round"></span>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must focus on a focusable item.  If you want to set it on something normally not focusable add tabindex=0.  There are a couple other quick tricks to make VO read the entire modal.  Add aria-labelledby="id_of_title" aria-describedby="id_of_content"  don't use the hash '#'.