# How can get voice over focus to my modal?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, voiceover

I am using Mac and with the voice over (accessibility) option on. I have my exit modal open on a link click and I set my keyboard focus on the modal (with js). This all works fine. However, the voice over focus is not switched to my modal, it is still on the trigger link.

How do I get the voice over focus to the modal? Here is the modal code:

```
<div class="modal-pattern" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true" data-analytics-location="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-icons-enabled" aria-label="modal-state" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <button class="-close--small" aria-label="Close" data-analytics-click="Close [X] Modal" data-analytics-type="button" data-dismiss="x-close">
              <img src="assets/images/icon-close.svg" alt="" />Close
            </button>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="modal-title">Modal</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p>Modal content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition, I know if the keyboard focus is not on an element that the keyboard can focus on naturally, then the voice over cursor will not move inside the modal.
So I think the one solution is putting the keyboard focus on the close button when the modal opens.
But I don't know how can I.
How can you help me?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094631/how-do-i-get-voice-over-focus-to-my-modal#:~:text=I%20was%20able%20to%20focus,button%20when%20the%20modal%20opens.

Comment: Thanks, @GrimReaper07 I already checked this question and answer. But I am not sure about the solution. Could you tell me the details?
I have not enough experience with screen reader and voice over.

Comment: You manually manage your focus when the modal opens. As your close button naturally takes focus it is a logical place to focus using `document.querySelector(".modal-pattern button").focus();` (or a better selector). That way the screen reader will read from within the modal. The other thing you need to do is track which button activated the modal and return focus to that button when the modal closes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61217687/2702894) I gave is complex but if you pick through the code you should get an idea of how it works.